# Linear temporal logic constraint

Tags: logic

I would like to express the following constraint in linear temporal logic.

**If A happens, then B must happen directly before it.**

I tried "B R !A" (!A remains true until B becomes true; B may never becomes true), but it is not correct as A may or may not happen after B happens.

Can any logic expert help me on this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Well, if X is read as next, i.e. Xp means in the next time step, p is the case, then Xp → q would be what you are looking for.

Or in your letters:  XA → B

(X is sometimes replaced with an N or a circle, but is always present in LTL.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use PT-LTL for this. Its past time LTL.
The formula would be
A -> X B, here X means previously.

You can use JavaMOP for implementation of PTLTL monitors.

Comment: Sorry, that's not true. You CAN use PT-LTL, but you don't need to. PT-LTL and LTL are equivalently expressive. LTL + past operators, however, can be more succinct (see Nicolas Markey's paper on this from 2003).